# xcode automatically opening all folders from project bundle when clicking on build and run button

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I facing trouble while running my application, My Xcode 5 is automatically opening all folders which are in my project folder on the desktop, Every time I'm running my project it open folders from project folder.

Comment: can you be more elaborative with further information and screenshots....

Comment: its like opening bunch of folders simultaneously.

Comment: have you found the problem and solution for it.Please share